# how to store CMD output in one array of strings in tcl script

Tags: cmd, tcl

I'm executing the below script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#!usr/bin/expect
package require Expect
spawn telnet $serverName $portNum
expect "TradeAggregator>"
send "Clients\r"
expect "Client:"
send "1\r"
expect "1-Client>"
send "Pollers\r"
expect "Client Pollers"
send "2\r"
```

After executing these lines:

```
send "Pollers\r"
expect ">"
```

I am getting below lines in CMD output:

```
"Client" Pollers
1) "ICTS_ICEFIX_Worker Worker" (ICTS_ICEFIX_Worker Poller): RUNNING
2) "NYMEX UTBAPI Worker" (NYMEX UTBAPI Poller): STOPPED
```

So here, I want to store the above output in one variable. Then I want to read it line by line and if any lines contains `NYMEX` word, then I need to fetch the first number (1) in this eg.) and perform some substring method to cut the sting.

How can I get this in tcl script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
# After you send "2\r":    
expect * ;# Do this to get data in expect_out

foreach line [split $expect_out(buffer) \n] {
    if {[string match *NYMEX* $line]} {
        set number [scan $line "%d"] ;# Do something with that number
    }
}
```

#### Discussion

- After you `send "2\r"`, we need to capture the output into a variable. Fortunately, *Expect* provides that with the built-in `expect_out` variable. All we need is to issue an `expect *` command
- The `foreach` loop splits the output into lines, and look for *NYMEX*, if found, we extract the first number and do something useful with it.